# UriMatcher Uri * and # difference

Tags: android, uri, android-contentprovider

I'm trying to implement my own `ContentProvider` based on few examples but I'm confused by different approaches in `UriMAtcher`. For instance:
[JavaDoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/UriMatcher.html) shows it with `#`like this:

```
sURIMatcher.addURI("contacts", "people", PEOPLE);
sURIMatcher.addURI("contacts", "people/#", PEOPLE_ID);
sURIMatcher.addURI("contacts", "people/#/phones", PEOPLE_PHONES);
sURIMatcher.addURI("contacts", "people/#/phones/#", PEOPLE_PHONES_ID);
```

but in "[iosched](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/provider/ScheduleProvider.java)" reference app by Google it uses `*` like this:

```
matcher.addURI(authority, "rooms", ROOMS);
matcher.addURI(authority, "rooms/*", ROOMS_ID);
matcher.addURI(authority, "rooms/*/sessions", ROOMS_ID_SESSIONS);
```

Can anybody explain the difference of these two approaches ?

Comment: URI nodes may be exact match string, the token "*" that matches any text, or the token "#" that matches only numbers. Source: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/UriMatcher.html

Comment: In case it helped you, kindly accept the answer. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Refer official docs : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/UriMatcher.html.

```
public void addURI (String authority, String path, int code)
```

Added in API level 1
Add a URI to match, and the code to return when this URI is matched. URI nodes may be exact match string, the token "*" that matches any text, or the token "#" that matches only numbers.